# Variance of Sum of 100 dice rolls?

Tags: probability, variance

If I roll 100 dice, I would expect the distribution of the sum to approach a normal distribution, right? Now, how can I calculate the variance and standard deviation of this distribution of the sum of 100 dice rolls. **Here's what I'm thinking:**

E[1 dice roll] = 3.5 // Variance[1 dice roll] = 2.91

**Variances[100 dice rolls]** = 100 * Variance[1 dice roll] = 291.

**Standard deviation[100 dice rolls]** = sqrt(291) = ~17

Is this correct? If it is correct, why is it that in this specific case I can simply add the variances?

Comment: Perhaps you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: If "100 dice rolls"="sum of 100 iid dice rolls", then we know that $V(X+Y)=V(X)+V(Y)$. In the more general case there is an additional covariance term which ruins the additivity of variances, but equal to $0$ for independent random variables.

Comment: If you take any random variable $X$ that corresponds to the results of running some sort of numerical trial once, and the random variable $Y$ is the total from $y$ independent trials of $X$, then we get that $E(Y)=yE(X), V(Y)=yV(X)$.  If the trials are not independent, this won't work